# GeoServer SLD applying two styles for one layer

Tags: geoserver, style, sld, xml

How can I apply two styles (NamedStyle and UserStyle). When executing a query, only the top one is applied. How can I apply both styles?

This sld_body:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
           <NamedLayer>
              <Name>${this.selectedValue.name}</Name>
              <NamedStyle>
                <Name>sld_well_o</Name>
              </NamedStyle>
              <UserStyle>
                 <Title>Heatmap</Title>
                 <Abstract>A heatmap surface showing GLOB distribution</Abstract>
                 <FeatureTypeStyle>
                    <Transformation>
                       <ogc:Function name="vec:Heatmap">
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>weightAttr</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Literal>${selectedField.name}</ogc:Literal>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>radiusPixels</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Function name="env">
                                <ogc:Literal>radius</ogc:Literal>
                                <ogc:Literal>${radius}</ogc:Literal>
                             </ogc:Function>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>pixelsPerCell</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>outputBBOX</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Function name="env">
                                <ogc:Literal>wms_bbox</ogc:Literal>
                             </ogc:Function>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>outputWidth</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Function name="env">
                                <ogc:Literal>wms_width</ogc:Literal>
                             </ogc:Function>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                             <ogc:Literal>outputHeight</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Function name="env">
                                <ogc:Literal>wms_height</ogc:Literal>
                             </ogc:Function>
                          </ogc:Function>
                       </ogc:Function>
                    </Transformation>
                    <Rule>
                       <RasterSymbolizer>
                          <Geometry>
                             <ogc:PropertyName>geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                          </Geometry>
                          <Opacity>${opacity}</Opacity>
                          <ColorMap type="ramp">
                             <ColorMapEntry color="#70ff00" quantity="0.0" label="nodata" opacity="0" />
                             <ColorMapEntry color="#8b8b8b" quantity="0.001" label="minValue" opacity="0" />
                             <ColorMapEntry color="${colorStart}" quantity=".1" label="start" />
                             <ColorMapEntry color="${colorEnd}" quantity="1.0" label="end" />
                          </ColorMap>
                       </RasterSymbolizer>
                    </Rule>
                 </FeatureTypeStyle>
              </UserStyle>
           </NamedLayer> 
        </StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

call WMS:

```
let sldBody = xmlRequest.replace(/\s\s+/gm, '');
this.heatMapLayer = (L as any).nonTiledLayer.wms(`${this.selectedValue.source.url}/wms`, {
  tileSize: L.point(map.getSize().x, map.getSize().y),
  format: 'image/png',
  sld_body: sldBody,
  version: '1.3.0',
  transparent: true,
  layers: this.selectedValue.name,
  cql_filter: `${selectedField.name} > 0`
});
```

Version GeoServer 2.15.0
I am using Lealflet

Comment: individually styles are applied

Comment: how are you calling the WMS?

Comment: @IanTurton edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only apply one style per layer in a WMS request so you will need to request the layer twice with the two styles.

So something like:

```
let sldBody1 = xmlRequest1.replace(/\s\s+/gm, '');
let sldBody2 = xmlRequest2.replace(/\s\s+/gm, '');
this.heatMapLayer = (L as any).nonTiledLayer.wms(`${this.selectedValue.source.url}/wms`, {
  tileSize: L.point(map.getSize().x, map.getSize().y),
  format: 'image/png',
  sld_body: sldBody1,sldBody2,
  version: '1.3.0',
  transparent: true,
  layers: this.selectedValue.name,this.selectedValue.name,
  cql_filter: `${selectedField.name} > 0`, `${selectedField.name} > 0`
});
```

Comment: only the first specified sldBody works

Comment: if this is set (sld_body: sldBody2, sldBody1,), then it activates only sldBody2 and vice versa

Comment: did you split the sld between the 2 variables?

Comment: yes 
`let xmlRequestOriginLayer = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2.1" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <NamedLayer>
      <Name>${this.selectedValue.name}</Name>
      <NamedStyle>
          <Name>sld_well_o</Name>
      </NamedStyle>
   </NamedLayer> 
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
;`

Comment: and the first without this part
 `<NamedStyle>
<Name> sld_well_o </ Name>
</ NamedStyle>`

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246140/sld-body-in-wms-layer-params-is-not-working for a longer discussion of what is probably happening

Comment: The query shows that it considers sldBody2 as the wms parameter, maybe this is the problem? 
`sld_body: sldBody1
sldBody2: ...`

Comment: this image  ![screenImage](https://i.ibb.co/7QRvFfm/image.png)

Comment: please edit your question to make it clearer and always copy and paste text don't use pictures of it

Comment: following the example of your answer, I was able to display the layer with two styles through the "styles" parameter, thanks for the help.