# How to load external SLD in Leaflet?

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, javascript

I am trying to style my WMS map using `sld_body` parameter as explained in [GeoServer working with SLD docs](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#external-styles). I tested with simple SLD file as below,

```js
var sld = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
   xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <NamedLayer>
      <Name>default_polygon</Name>
      <UserStyle>
        <Title>Default Polygon</Title>
        <Abstract>A sample style that draws a polygon</Abstract>
        <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <Rule>
            <Name>rule1</Name>
            <Title>Gray Polygon with Black Outline</Title>
            <Abstract>A polygon with a gray fill and a 1 pixel black outline</Abstract>
            <PolygonSymbolizer>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#AAAAAA</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
              <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
              </Stroke>
            </PolygonSymbolizer>
          </Rule>
        </FeatureTypeStyle>
      </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
  </StyledLayerDescriptor>
  `;
```

Then I tried to add the style as below,

```js
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?sld_body=" + sld,
    {
      layers: "topp:layer_name",
      format: "image/png",
      styles: "",
      transparent: true,
      attribution: "mylayer",
    }
  );
```

Now I can't access my WMS layer. In geoserver log file, it shows the `XML` error as below,

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 
814; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.                                                                                                          
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)                                           
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)                                    
at org.geotools.xml.styling.SLDParser.parseSLD(SLDParser.java:470)                                                      
... 122 more
```

In GeoServer docs, it explains **The SLD XML must be URL-encoded.** So I tried to encode this SLD using `encodeURI` as below,

```js
sld = encodeURI(sld)

var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
    "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?sld_body=" + sld,
    {
      layers: "topp:layer_name",
      format: "image/png",
      styles: "",
      transparent: true,
      attribution: "mylayer",
    }
  );
```

The layer is still not visible. I checked the GeoServer log and found this error,

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 20; columnNumber: 43; 
XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.                                                                                                          
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)                                           
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)                                    
at org.geotools.xml.styling.SLDParser.parseSLD(SLDParser.java:470)                                                      
... 122 more
```

I verified that the same SLD is working when I uploaded it to the GeoServer.

Comment: Have you checked the answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/246185/108903)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me quote the [Leaflet API reference about `L.TileLayer.WMS`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tilelayer-wms):

> If any custom options not documented here are used, they will be sent to the WMS server as extra parameters in each request URL. This can be useful for non-standard vendor WMS parameters.

Thus, instead of ...

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?sld_body=" + sld,
  {
    layers: "topp:layer_name",
    // ...etc
```

... you should do something like ...

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.wms(
  "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms/reflect?",
  {
    layers: "topp:layer_name",
    sld_body: sld,
    // ...etc
```

...this way, Leaflet will internally  apply `encodeURIComponent` (and *not* `encodeURI`) to all the extra parameters.

Note that the outputs of `encodeURIComponent(sld)` and `encodeURI(sld)` are different.

Comment: Great!!! This solution worked. Also, I added the `<IsDefault>1</IsDefault> ` inside `UserStyle` node in my sld. Now it is working fine. Thank you very much.