# Refer to other SLD in geoserver for GetLegendGraphic

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld, getlegendgraphic

I have a group layer in geoserver with all layers having one style each.

However, for the legend I want to refer to an "external" SLD (basically a simplified "dummy legend"). The SLD is in the same workspace as the group layer and I guess you can specify the SLD you want to get by GetLegendGraphic Parameters? Here specifically, I'm thinking of the SLD parameter.

The solution (I think) is something like this:

https://wms.myserver.com/geoserver/my_workspace/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=30&HEIGHT=30&LAYER=my_group_layer&SLD=**???**

In the SLD documentation it says thatt you can refer to an external SLD by a URL. How do i know what URL to use as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your style is already published by GeoServer then you can just use the `style` parameter in the `GetLegend` request:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&format=image%2Fpng&width=20&height=20&layer=topp%3Astates&style=pophatch
```

If you need to send specific SLD then the process is the same as sending it for a layer as discussed in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246140/sld-body-in-wms-layer-params-is-not-working) and the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/working.html#external-styles)

Comment: Makes perfect sense, problem solved! Thanks!